# How to prove an inequality $\left| {g(j + 1)} \right| \le 5/4$ in Stein's method for Poisson approximation

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, approximation-theory

The following is a lemma in

Barbour, A. D., Holst, L., & Janson, S. (1992). Poisson approximation. Oxford: Clarendon Press,p7.

For $j=1,2,...$ and $\lambda  > 0$, we have

$\left| {g(j + 1)} \right| \le {(\lambda  - j)^{ - 1}}$ if $j < \lambda $;

and

$\left| {g(j + 1)} \right| \le \frac{{j + 2}}{{(j + 1)(j + 2 - \lambda )}}$ if $j > \lambda  - 2$.

How to prove that $\left| {g(j + 1)} \right| \le 5/4$ for all $\lambda  > 0$ and  $j=1,2,...$?

The book ignores the proof.

Comment: You have an upper bound on the interval $(-\infty,\lambda)$ and an upper bound on the interval $(\lambda-2,\infty)$ and these intervals overlap, so I would assume that just checking with basic calculus will tell you the maximum on each interval minus the overlap, then you just calculate the min of the two upper bounds on the overlap. What goes wrong with this very natural approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $k = \frac{(2j + 1)(j + 2)}{2j + 3}$.  It's easy to see that $k$ is strictly between $j$ and $j + 2$.  If $\lambda \ge k$, then by the first inequality, $|g(j + 1)| \le \frac{1}{\lambda - j} \le \frac{1}{k - j} = \frac{2j + 3}{2j + 2}$.  If $\lambda \le k$, then by the second inequality, $|g(j + 1)| \le \frac{(j + 2)}{(j + 1)(j + 2 - \lambda)} \le \frac{(j + 2)}{(j + 1)(j + 2 - k)} = \frac{2j + 3}{2j + 2}$.  So either way, $|g(j + 1)| \le \frac{2j + 3}{2j + 2}$.  Because $j \ge 1$, it follows that $|g(j + 1)| \le \frac{5}{4}$.